# Setting expiration for IDistributedCache.SetAsync while using AddDistributedRedisCache

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, redis-cache

I am using .net core api (2.1) with aws redis cache. I don't see a way to set expiration to the [IDistributedCache.SetAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.idistributedcache.setasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Distributed_IDistributedCache_SetAsync_System_String_System_Byte___Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Distributed_DistributedCacheEntryOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_). How is it possible?

My code segment is below:

```
// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
    {
        var redisCacheUrl = Configuration["RedisCacheUrl"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(redisCacheUrl))
        {
            options.Configuration = redisCacheUrl;
        }
    });
}
```

```
//Set & GetCache
public async Task<R> GetInsights<R>(string cacheKey, IDistributedCache _distributedCache)
{
    var encodedResult = await _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(cacheKey);               

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(encodedResult))
    {
    var cacheValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<R>(encodedResult);
    return cacheValue;
    }

    var result = GetResults<R>(); //Call to resource access
    var encodedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    await _distributedCache.SetAsync(cacheKey, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedResult)); //Duration?

    return result;
}
```

How long the cache is available? How can I set an expiration time? If that is not possible, how can I remove the cache?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's in the `options` param. You pass an instance of [`DistributedCacheEntryOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.distributedcacheentryoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which has various properties you can utilize to set the expire time. For example:

```
await _distributedCache.SetAsync(cacheKey, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedResult), new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
{
    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
});
```